# Display UITextField input as UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uitextfield

How can I get the users input (a link) and display it on another screen (using the same view controller) as a UIWebView?

Comment: What you tried so far ? show your code.

Answer (score 0):

How about using interface builder to set up your project, adding a `UITextField` on top of your view controller's view and a `UIWebView` right beneath?!

Comment: No...that's not what I meant at all. I'm trying to get the link that the user enters from one screen and display that link in the web view on another screen.